# Photoshop -- inaccurate 1 pixel brush/pencil

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mac

I've seen a lot of stuff about this, but everything I've tried has not helped my problem.

I made a custom 1 px brush using the marquee tool (seems like the default 1px pencil should also work fine though) and I am finding it to be extremely inaccurate on my `MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014)` running `Sierra 10.12.6 (16G29)`

I think I have the settings configured right with no options turned on in the
[brush palette](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAjjl.png) and square pixel ratio turned on under `view -> Pixel Aspect Ratio`

The pixel grid seems aligned properly, yet when I go to make a mark using this custom 1px brush, or the 1px pencil tool, I get the following effect in many (but not all) cases:

[image]

The pixel will be drawn one or more squares away. What other settings could influence this?

I set up these squares for a sprite sheet using 20px by 20px squares, which seem to have formed properly judging by the grid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your problem is that you are snapping to the 20 px grid.

Turn off `View/Snap To/Grid`.